# Zurb Foundation : Topbar menu button on medium

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I would like to display the menu button and collapse my topbar in small and medium screen sizes, and not just in small size like the default behavior.

I tried something with setting this:

```
$topbar-breakpoint: #{upper-bound($large-range)}; // Change to 9999px for always mobile layout
```

But it doesn't seems to work...

Comment: Me too and its a damn shame this hasn't gotten any hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `_settings.scss` uncomment

```
// $topbar-breakpoint: #{upper-bound($medium-range)};
// $topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{upper-bound($medium-range)})";
```

$topbar-breakpoint, $topbar-media-query are using `upper-bound` getting high value from the breakpoint `var`, which is actually an array 64.xxem and 90em.

now instead of `upper-bound use lower bound` like the below..

```
$topbar-breakpoint: #{lower-bound($large-range)};
$topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{lower-bound($large-range)})"
```

let me know if i am missing something! i did not test this because i never use the less files but I think that is how it works!

Comment: i don't use them either, but i already made for myself a cheap workaround, providing a better answer isn't given. i appreciate you taking the time to answer the question!

Comment: lol i dont understand -- you are not the one that asked the question @r3wt

Comment: i know, rather than ask a duplicate question, i revived it and placed the bounty. i was stuck on the same problem.